# How do I extract the number before a text with variable spacing in r?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to capture all the numbers with G right after them ( I only want the number). I have tried the following but it won't give me the one followed right by G.

```
a="1.1G;1.2 G;1.435 G;1.1   G;1.5555G"
 stringr::str_extract_all(a, "(?<!\\d)\\d+\\.*\\d*(?=\\s*G)\\b")
```

so I would want all the numbers extracted from the above because all the numbers are followed by G ( it doesn't matter if there is spacing between the numbers and the letter G)

so I would expect the extract to have:

1.1, 1.2,1.435,1.1,1.5555

Comment: Like this? `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*G)` https://regex101.com/r/4ljlWt/1

Comment: Please share the expected output. E.g. waht does "one followed right by G" mean? Are spaces allowed like in "1.2 G" or ont?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the negative lookbehind as the match already starts with the first digit, and match digits with an optional decimal part asserting what is on the right is a G allowing optional whitespace chars.

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*G)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ljlWt/1/) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/RlCo5X)

```
a="1.1G;1.2 G;1.435 G;1.1   G;1.5555G"
stringr::str_extract_all(a, "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=\\s*G\\b)")
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "1.1"    "1.2"    "1.435"  "1.1"    "1.5555"
```

Comment: Thank you! this helps, what if I have 1G/1ML can I exclude that?

Comment: @Mel You could use a negative lookahead asserting what is directly to the right of the `G` is for example not `/` like `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*G(?!/))` https://regex101.com/r/TORBDR/1